# how to return a object in a function that takes arguments visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

Hi im trying to write a function that returns an object but it gives me an arguments not optional error, this is my code

```
Public Function searchVehicle(c As String, v As Variant) As Collection
  Dim qur As String
  qur = "select * from [vehicle] where ( " & c & " like '%" & v & "%')"
  Set mobjRst = conn.execQuery(qur)
  Dim tmpV As Vehicle
  Dim res As Collection
  With mobjRst
   Do Until .EOF
    Set tmpV = New Vehicle
    Call tmpV.popVehicle(!ID, !make, !model, !purchaseyear, !totalmilage, !milageafterservice, !servicemilage, !description)
    res.Add (tmpV)
    .MoveNext
   Loop
  End With
searchVehicle = res
End Function
```

Comment: What line does the error appear on?

Comment: Not showing us the line of code that causes error, it's most likely your Vehicle class' popVehicle method - but until your tell us what line it is on... it's a guess

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that since it's an object reference, you need to use `Set` to set the return value.

```
Set searchVehicle = res
```

It may be more helpful to know what line you're seeing the problem on.

As a side note, you may also want to take a look at when you need to use Call and when you don't: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i needed, i don't know how i missed that

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the following call to the function -

```
searchVehicle = res
```

You have specified searchVehicle to have a string (c) and a variant (v) combining a collection. This will error as you have set no values to either c or v and then call your function -

```
searchVehicle = (c, v) collection
```

give us some more information on how you call this etc in your button click event, what is returned...